# Compiling Python from source: multiple threads for tests?

Tags: python, makefile, compilation

I compile Python **3.6** from sources using:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=/local/py/path
make -j8
```

The compilation itself runs on 8 threads as expected when passing `-j8` to `make`. However, since I also use `--enable-optimizations` I read that skipping tests is not recommended, but the tests run sequentially and *only* on one thread leading to very long compilation time.

Is there something I could do to let the tests be executed on multiple threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not build Python often enough to prompt me to have a closer look (once or twice after each release tops), but you've given me an extra impulse and I've poked around a bit.

I presume you're referring to (currently) 406 tests executed as part of building the default target. That would mean the `run_profile_task` target of its `Makefile`.  Which runs `python -m test.regrtest --pgo` with your freshly built interpreter as defined in the `PROFILE_TASK` make variable.

Long story short, instead of of:

```
make -j8
```

You can run:

```
make PROFILE_TASK="-m test.regrtest --pgo -j8" -j8
```

Which just repeats the default definition (as of now) and appends `-j8` which conveniently is the same as the one used by make.

And since I am a curious person, I had to try comparing both. On the machine I currently got booted up (not a very beefy laptop) it reduced regression test times from ~23 min to ~8 min. So, thanks for an excuse to look around, this may come in handy. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe running these test in parallel will probably not yield the wanted results.
This tests.regrtest --pgo is run to train the optimizations you turned on.
They are the benchmark used for the training purpose of these optimizations, since certain optimizations might have different performance impacts on different systems.

I believe the main purpose is to get a feel for what the ideal sizes for certain structures are such that your cpu caches are used to their full potential.

Running these tests in parallel might let the test interfere with each other cpu caches, and not give the wanted results.
However, I did no testing, it might as well be that if you are going to run different tasks in parallel all the time this might actually be beneficial, but in that case perhaps you should write your own benchmark suite that best matches your tasks?

The typical speedups seen by these tests can be found here:
https://bugs.python.org/issue24915