# How to run tests while building Python 3.10+ from source?

Tags: python, compilation, python-3.10

Unlike earlier version 3 releases nowadays building Python 3.10 from source does not seem to run the (time-consuming) tests.

I need to build Python 3.10 on an oldish platform (no, I can't change that). I would actually like to run the tests, even if they are time consuming.

Unfortunately, I can't find the way to do it. Googling shows nonsensical results (how to do testing while using Python, `unittest` etc), while `./configure --help` doesn't show anything.

Have the tests been removed? If not, how can I enable them?

Comment: "Googling shows nonsensical results (how to do testing while using Python, unittest etc)" Did you try searching for `compile python from source run tests`? Because that is the first thing I thought of trying, and the first result I got - [not even from Google](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=compile+python+from+source+run+tests) - was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49793880/compiling-python-from-source-multiple-threads-for-tests) which seems much closer to the mark (although it's not for 3.10, it might point you in the right direction).

Comment: And [this](https://docs.python.org/3/using/configure.html#main-makefile-targets)

Comment: How about the [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/configure.html#configure-options)? Alternately, you could try the Python mailing list.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've just searched "compile python from source run tests" in google. It shows nothing but  "python without running tests". Obviously, Google shows different results to different people. It's not the first time I've seen the situation of one guy not seeing the relevant result that another guy searched for but doesn't get it in search results. Well I didn't think of asking for it in duckduckgo etc.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel And this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49793880/compiling-python-from-source-multiple-threads-for-tests does not show how to **enable** running tests when they're not ran by default at all. It's a question asked in 2018 when IIRC tests where ran by default when building.

Comment: Okay, and how about the documentation link, specifically where @DeepSpace anchored it?

Answer (score 0):

Building from source `make -j 4 prefix="/usr"` usually does the tests too. At least that's what I've observed.